# Proving a uniform bound given that $0<A-f\leq B$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, soft-question

I've been working in the following problem. The problem itself is quite large and involves many steps, but the point is that I'm in a step where I have a certain open set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and some function $f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb R$. I've already proven that there exists **positive constants**  $A, B>0$ such that for all $x \in \Omega,$
$$ 0<A-f(x)\leq B. $$
How can I prove that there exists some $C>0$ such that $\| f \|\leq C$ ? (Here I'm refering to the uniform norm) Moreover, how can I choose an optimal $C$ explicitely depending on $A$ and $B$? I think $C=|B-A|+A$ might work but I'm not sure if it is optimal.

Comment: $f(x)<A$ and $f(x)\ge A-B.$ Hence $\|f\|\le \max (A,B-A).$